# Is it possible to change from a PSN Sub Account to a Master Account

Tags: ps3, psn

I brought a Playstation 3 when it was released and I was under 18, so my older brother took the Master Account. Now that I have turned 18 and my brother is moving out, I now have the PS3 to myself however I am still on a sub account. I have tried changing but can't find any way to do this.

My brother plans to buy a PS3 in the future keeping the same PSN ID.

If it's impossible to change account type then is it possible to give more priviledges to a sub account such as controlling finance, facebook integration etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend calling Sony customer support.

Comment: +1. As this option isn't available anywhere, you'll have to look into getting into contact with Sony themselves.